# Remove Shadow in GeocoderAutoCompleteView - Mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox

How do I remove the border shadow in:
com.mapbox.services.android.geocoder.ui.GeocoderAutoCompleteView

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide your XML for the geocoder? The geocoding widget extends EditText therefore, you should be able to change the styling similar to an edittext. In the demo app the xml for the widget looks like this:

```
<com.mapbox.services.android.geocoder.ui.GeocoderAutoCompleteView
    android:id="@+id/query"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:elevation="12dp"
    android:hint="Search Location"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
```

removing the `android:elevation="12dp"` removes the "shadow".

on a side note, from the screenshot above, the shadow actually looks pretty good ;)

Comment: Agh, I didn't realize I had the elevation attribute set on the bottom.  Anywho, thanks again @cammace!! :D